# Test React component method and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing some tests for my React Component.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class CityFilter extends React.Component {

    handleSelect = selectedCity => {
        this.props.cityFilterChanged(selectedCity)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Dropdown data={this.props.cityData}
                      onSelect={this.handleSelect}
            />
        )
    }

    export function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return { cityData: state.Cities.cityData }
    }

    export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators({
            cityFilterChanged
        }, dispatch);
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CityFilter));
```

I ran the following test using `jest` and `enzyme`:

```
import cityFilterChanged from '../../actions/cityFilterChanged';
import DropDown from '../components/DropDown';
import {mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps } from '../CityFilter';

describe('Test cases for CityFilter Component', () => {
    const dummyCityData = []; // contains lists of cities
    const wrapper = mount(
        <CityFilter
            cityData={dummyCityData}
        />);

    wrapper.instance().handleSelect = jest.fn();

    it('calls handleSelect on selecting a value', () => {
        wrapper.find('checkbox').first().simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.instance().handleSelect).toBeCalled(); // passes
    });

    it('tests mapDispatchToProps function', () => {
        expect(mapDispatchToProps()).toEqual({
            cityFilterChanged
        });
    })
});
```

When I check the code coverage for `CityFilter` component (after running the coverage command), I see that `handleSelect` was not covered/executed by the test, even though the test regarding `toBeCalled` is passing. I am aiming for a test coverage of hundred percent, so how can I make sure that my test successfully runs `handleSelect`?

Also, the test regarding `mapDispatchToProps` is failing, giving the error:

```
Expected: {"cityFilterChanged": [Function anonymous]}
Received: serializes to the same string
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you are mocking `handleSelect` and not testing it directly so you can try to remove the mock and test that when called, `handleSelect` produced the desired effects:

```
describe('Test cases for CityFilter Component', () => {
    const dummyCityData = []; // contains lists of cities
    const wrapper = mount(
        <CityFilter
            cityData={dummyCityData}
        />);

    it('calls handleSelect on selecting a value', () => {
        wrapper.find('checkbox').first().simulate('click');
        // Assert that cityFilter value has been updated
    });
});
```

Comment: If I remove `wrapper.instance().handleSubmit = jest.fn();`, then the test fails, giving the error: `Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]`

Comment: You shouldn't test `mapDispatchToProps` but that `handleSelect` updated the state correctly.